# Set of linear equations with coefficients - solution using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have a set of linear equations:
\begin{matrix}
 ax_{1}&  {}+bx_{2}&  {}+x_{3}&  & =0\\ 
 cx_{1}&  {}+dx_{2}&  &{}-x_{4}  & =0\\ 
 &  {}-ex_{2}&  {}+cx_{3}&  {}+ax_{4}& =0\\ 
 &  {}+ex_{2}&  {}+dx_{3}&  {}+bx_4& =0
\end{matrix}
I should find the conditions for the coeficients $(a,b,\ldots)$, so that this set of linear equations has a non-zero solution. I should use a matrix or determinant or any solution based on matrices, because it is what we are learning at the school now.

Sorry if I made any mistakes. I am not so good in English.

Thank You for Your help!!!!

**UPDATE:**

Regarding @Alex Silva answer, I've constucted the matrix A made of the coefficients in front of each x:

$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &1  &0 \\ 
c &d  &0  &-1 \\ 
0 &-e  &c  &a \\ 
0 &e  &d  &b 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then I transposed the matrix so that I could check the linear dependence of its columns:
$
A^{T} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a &c  &0  &0 \\ 
b &d  &-e  &e \\ 
1 &0  &c  &d \\ 
0 &-1  &a  &b 
\end{pmatrix} \sim 
\begin{pmatrix}  
1 &0  &c  &d \\ 
0 &-1  &a  &b \\
b &d  &-e  &e \\
a &c  &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Having the Gaussian elimination in mind, I thought: under the main diagonal I should have only zero. So **b, d, a, c = 0**

Then:
$
A^{T}=
\begin{pmatrix}  
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &-1  &0  &0 \\
0 &0  &-e  &e \\
0 &0  &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}
$

I transpose the $A^{T}$ back and I get:

$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &-1  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-e  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &e  &0 
\end{pmatrix}
$

The last two lines are linearly dependent and I always get an non-zero solution. **e** can be any number.

Am I right?

Comment: Your problem is of the form $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$. What is $\mathbf{A}$ in your case (try to write it down)? Clearly, $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is always a trivial solution. When are there more (non-trivial) solutions (what are the conditions on $\mathbf{A}$ for this to happen)?

Comment: @m.a. Didn't you want to comment Alex Silva's answer :-) ?

Comment: I did not realized there was an answer when I was typing my comment. Alex's answer gives more specific clues than my comment.

Comment: @m.a. Sorry, I didn't realize that your comment can be understood also as an answer. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Construct the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, and assure the linear dependence of its columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please be more specific regarding the linear dependence of the columns? I've constructed the matrix A (it is a matrix made of the coefficients in front of each x, am I right?), but I don't know what to do further. In the school we were checking the linear dependence of the vectors within the matrix by converting it on a triangular matrix, but will it help me?

Comment: OK, so I used the Gaussian elimination. Is my approach under the UPDATE correct :-) ?

Comment: @Juice, your matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is correct, but I did not understand why you set the main block diagonal to zero. Notice that if $a=c=0$ and $b,d \neq 0$, we have a solution. I suggest you applying the method step-by-step. I think the solution is a polynomial equation (or system) on $a,b,c,d$ and $e$. :)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But why should I check the linear dependence of the COLUMNS and not the rows? Because as we learned it in school the number up results is dependent on the rank of the matrix A with the matrix of results added as the last column ( we will call it B) . If the rank of the matrix A is equal to the rank of B, then the system of equations has at least one solution. If the rank is equal to the number of unknowns, then it has one non-zero result, except the homogeneous system, which has only zero ( trivial) solution.

Comment: And when the number of unknowns is higher than the rank, then it has an indefinite number of results and it is also the only case in which the homogeneous has a non-trivial solution. But you always check the linear dependence of the rows to keep each of the variables in its own column while using the Gauss-Jordan elimination , so I don't get why I am checking the linear dependence of the columns.

Comment: @Juice,  you can also check linear dependence of the rows. But, forget the Gauss Elimination method for that. This is not complicated but the computation is boring. I suggest you to calculate the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$ and the linear dependence with the determinant is very easy to assure.

Comment: So I should rather use the Laplace's formula for calculating the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

The condition on the coefficients for your system to have a non-zero solution is to ensure that the rank of your matrix is less than 4 (the number of variables).  This is the same as saying that your equations must be linearly dependent.

Also, you don't need to transpose your matrix or distinguish in any way between rows and columns, because for any matrix the row-rank and column-rank (and determinant-rank if the matrix is square) are all the same.